# How can use Regex.IsMatch to find if there are any letter with accents(é, á, à, etc.)

Tags: c#

Hello I have this code:

```
string _name = this.txtNome.Text;
if ( Regex.IsMatch(_name, @"[^a-zA-Z\s]") ) 
    return false;
```

And I was trying to find a way to able characters like "é, á, í, etc.".

I tried to search but I didn't found anything.

Comment: Do you want to match only letters with accent, or any letters with or withou accent?

Comment: I want to match letters with and with out accent

Comment: Take a look at the named Unicode character blocks https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-classes-in-regular-expressions#supported-named-blocks

Comment: @Vitor.Batista.309: Did any of the answers your received help you with your issue?

Comment: I used my method.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know a regex that supports all accents, but you could use this extension-method:

```
public static class StringExtensions{
    public static IEnumerable<char> GetAccentCharacters(this string text)
    {
        foreach(char c in text)
        {
            string normalizedChars = c.ToString().Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD);
            if(normalizedChars.Length == 2 && normalizedChars[1] == '\u0301')
                yield return c;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
string input = "é, á, í, etc.";
string accentChars = string.Concat(input.GetAccentCharacters())
Console.Write(accents);
```

I use [`String.Normalize`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.normalize?view=net-5.0#System_String_Normalize_System_Text_NormalizationForm_) to split the accent characters into two to find the `'\u0301'`-char for the accent. Then i return the original `char`.

Read: [Character encoding in .NET - Grapheme clusters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-encoding-introduction#grapheme-clusters)

Comment: Nice. Side note: I'm pretty sure there is more than just accents decomposed as result of Normalization. So before using code in production make sure to harden it to account for all sorts of other decomposed parts.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: Yes, i haven't really tested it, so it should be used with caution. I have also edited it now since the original version was not working. You can't find the original char in the naive way i have used before. I think you need to use `Normalize` with every char in the string.

Comment: @Vitor.Batista.309: not sure why it's complex now that you have an extension method that gives you what you wanted. It's also easy to extend if you want to include for example circumflex accent(`\u005E`).

Comment: I don't find this one an easy way to do it sorry, I knew that was something less complex, but thank you really.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example that uses Regex [*Unicode Blocks*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-classes-in-regular-expressions#unicode-category-or-unicode-block-p) and the associated [*Named Blocks*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-classes-in-regular-expressions#supported-named-blocks).  I don't think it answers your question exactly (it's hard to tell what your question is exactly).  You'll need to fool around with it a bit to suit your needs.

Here's the text I'm going to look at:

```
private const string input =
    @"J’étais étudiant à Trois Rivières, Québec.  NotA123WordNumbers  
      Mon école primaire était St-François d’Assisse. J’avais du fun a Noël. 
      J’ai un chapeau sur ma tête Some Spanish: Acuña, Cámara, País, Corazón, 
      Número, Lingüística";
```

Here's the pattern I'm going to use:

```
private const string pattern = @"[\p{IsBasicLatin}\p{IsLatin-1Supplement}\p{IsLatinExtended-A}\p{IsLatinExtended-B}-[ ,\.0-9]]+";
private static readonly Regex _regex = new Regex(pattern);
```

The `\p{some-name}` element is a *named block*.  The weird `[ABC-[ ,\.0-9]]` means everything in the first pattern *minus* what's in the second pattern.  This is [*Character Class Subtraction*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-classes-in-regular-expressions#character-class-subtraction-base_group---excluded_group).

What is says is:

- Consider a grouping that consists of anything in any of the `IsBasicLatin`, `IsLatin-1Supplement`, `IsLatinExtended-A`, or `IsLatinExtended-B` character groups,
- That is not a space, a comma, a period or a digit.
- Match a pattern consists of one of more of those.

Then I run this code:

```
var matches = _regex.Matches(input);
foreach (var match in matches.Cast<Match>())
{
    Debug.WriteLine(match.Value);
}
```

and the output looks like this:

```
J
étais
étudiant
à
Trois
Rivières
Québec
NotA
WordNumbers


Mon
école
primaire
était
St-François
d
Assisse
J
avais
du
fun
a
Noël


J
ai
un
chapeau
sur
ma
tête
Some
Spanish:
Acuña
Cámara
País
Corazón


Número
Lingüística
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone needs I actually figured out an easier way to do it.

If you go to the ascii table the "À" is the first letter with accent and the "ÿ" is the last one so the code comes like this:

```
if ( Regex.IsMatch(_name, @"[^a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ\s]") ) 
    return false;
```

of course there is some especial caracters in the middle but I don't think that someone will miss click an "Ð" writing his name.